# Is it possible to suppress stacktrace from specific exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception, jaxb, stack-trace

I am currently developing a Java application which uses the `JaxbContext.newInstance()` method to instantiate a JaxbContext for deserializing XML. However, when I invoke the method using IntelliJ debug mode, I constantly
1) get an enormous stacktrace based on an InvocationTargetException thrown after invocation
2) But my application runs just fine, and the desired Context is correctly instantiated.

The issue only happens locally, and never when deployed using a .war file. Preferably I would like to stop the Exception from being thrown, but since I have tried to solve this for so long and my console gets so bloated, I can accept just suppressing the message sent to the console for errors that are due to that specific line. Is that possible?

Comment: Just to exclude things you already tried, have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000550/webservice-returns-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception)?

Comment: Yes, but it did not seem to reach a conclusion (an answer), and issue also seemed to be related to a SOAP service, which is not the case for me.

Comment: Did you look at the final “Caused by” section of that stack trace?  It might be something important.  I would not ignore it just because things “seem to work.”

Comment: It is caused by that exception. And it claims to be incapable of invoking a method of an object that I absolutely know to exist (also with the correct signature). An as I said, the unmarshalling happens the way I would expect. Hence, I really would insist on ignoring that specific error. In general, I would agree upon not accepting this - but I would rather do this, than have an error which I am accustomed to ignore in the log.